# What are the charges of all planets in our solar system?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, astrophysics, planets

What are the charges of all the planets
in our solar system and what are the charges of whole universe, solar system and milky way etc..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking what the total *electric* charge of planets and galaxies etc. are, the answer is that *on average* planets and other large scale structures in the universe have neutral charge.